# Asterisk autodial and play recording

Tags: asterisk

I am trying to originate a call using rawman, sending a phone number (57522666) as a parameter and playing a message to the answering party.

This is what I have so far:

```
http://192.168.11.11:8088/rawman?action=originate&channel=????&context=outboundmsg1&exten=s&priority=1&timeout=30000
```

And in extensions.conf:

```
[outboundmsg1]
exten => s,1,Answer
exten => s,2,Wait(1)
exten => s,3,Background(custom/message)
exten => t,1,Playback(vm-goodbye)
exten => t,2,Hangup
```

I have a SIP ATA as trunk with the following name:  23656429

I have no clue what to put in the channel parameter. I have tried SIP/23656429@57522666, but I don't get the outbound call.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else runs into this question... I got it to work by using the following:

```
http://192.168.11.11:8088/rawman?action=originate&channel=SIP/23656429/57522666&context=outboundmsg1&exten=s&priority=1&timeout=30000&callerid=23656429
```

And in extensions.conf

```
[outboundmsg1]
exten => s,1,Answer
exten => s,2,WaitExten()
exten => s,n,Wait(1)
exten => s,n,Playback(custom/elcodigo)         ; "play outbound msg"
exten => s,n,SayDigits(1498)
exten => 2,n, Wait(1)
exten => s,n,Hangup
```

Comment: You should not do allow functions like that without auth on your pbx. This is very insecure.

Comment: Thanks.  There is a previous authentication step that allows this route to work.  It is also protected by a firewall and ip whitelist.